# Displaying random sprites from a sprite sheet in Corona

Tags: random, lua, coronasdk, sprite

Very new to Corona and trying to make a simple memory game. I want to flash about 5 random sprites from a spritesheet (containing about 20 sprites) and then ask the user to input what they thought flash up while showing the sheet. Hope I've explained that OK? I've done a little bit of JavaScript before but would not be confident in coding. Trying to do something challenging - may have to do something simpler. Was told Corona was a good place to start :(
Would math.random be the correct way to go about it?

Any ideas I would be grateful. At the moment I can only display the whole sheet not sure how to make the random sprites appear.

Comment: This is asking for a tutorial, not for an answer to a practical problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some more in-depth example, that should help you out with building that system up (the previous answer has some a mistake)

```
local cards = {{name="one",count=0,flipped=false,matched=false},{name="two",count=0,flipped=false,matched=false},{name="three",count=0,flipped=false,matched=false},{name="four",count=0,flipped=false,matched=false},{name="five",count=0,flipped=false,matched=false},{name="six",count=0,flipped=false,matched=false}};
function getAvailableCards(Count)
    local suitable_cards = (Count and {} or nil); -- create a table if you want to get keys of a valid cards in the cards table
    local empty = true;
    for key,data in pairs(cards) do
        if (data.count < 2)then
            if (Count) then -- add key if you want an output (table with valid keys)
                table.insert(suitable_cards,key);
                -- table.insert(suitable_cards,key); you can insert it again for higher range of numbers to select from, making math.random a bit more "random".
                empty = false;
            else
                return true;
            end
        end
    end
    if (empty) then
        return false;
    end
    return suitable_cards;
end
function getRandomCard()
    local valid_cards = getAvailableCards(true); -- get a table with all valid keys of the cards table, to pick a random key
    if (not valid_cards) then
        return valid_cards; -- return false
    end
    local index = valid_cards[math.random(1,#valid_cards)]; -- select random key
    cards[index].count = cards[index].count + 1; -- increase the count of key generation
    return cards[index].name,index -- return card id and index from the cards table
end
function setupCards()
    while getAvailableCards() do
        local card_id,index = getRandomCard(); -- gets a random card id and it's index
        -- setup the card in GUI and such,
        -- like create a board and then create an image and load the image (based on card id)
        -- As an example (no such functions, but you should create them or find functions similiar to them)
        -- card = getBoard().NewImage();
        -- card.id = index;
        -- card.loadImage("hidden_card.png");
    end
end
function TryToMatch()
    local child1,child2 -- child tables that will be copied from the cards table, for later comparing
    -- get all flipped but not matched cards
    for key,child in pairs(cards) do
        if (child.flipped and not child.matched) then
            if (child1) then
                child2 = key; -- get key
            else
                child1 = key; -- get key
            end
        end
    end
    if ( child1 and child2) then -- two revealed cards can be checked
        if (child1.name == child2.name) then -- reveal
            cards[child1].matched,cards[child2].matched = true,true;
            TryToEnd();
        else
            --un-reveal it
        end
    end
end
function TryToEnd()
    local matched = 0;
    for key,child in pairs(cards) do
        if (child.flipped and child.matched) then
            matched = matched + 1;
        end
    end
    if (#cards == matched) then
        -- display that the game is finished
    end
end
function Click(object)
    -- When an object is clicked make it call this function with the object
    if (object and object.id and cards[object.id] and not (cards[object.id].flipped and cards[object.id].matched)) then
        cards[object.id].flipped = true;
        -- You should load here the card image (actual card image, like you revealed the card)
        -- Example
        -- object.loadImage(cards[object.id].name.. ".png");
        TryToMatch();
        return true
    end
    return false
end
```

EDIT:
I did not test this script nor use Corona, it may have some bugs, in theory it should work as it is.

Comment: Can you please tell me where is the mistake in the previous answer so I can correct? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A common technique used in games to get a random object from a collection is to use a random generated number like `math.random` and then use the modulo operator `%` to get a number from `0` to `number of objects`.

For example lets say you have a list of cards:

```
local cards = {"one","two","three","four","five"};
local numCards = #cards;
```

If you want to randomly select a card you can do the following:

```
local function getRandomCard()
    #This will give you a random number from 0 to 100
    math.randomseed(os.time())
    local randomNumber = math.random(100);

    #This will give a random number from 0 to 4. 
    local randomIndex = randomNumber % numCards; 
    # Lua indices start at 1, so we add this to our index
    randomIndex = randomIndex + 1; #This will get us a number from 1 to 5; =)

    return cards[randomIndex];
end
```

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I think I'm on the right track then I have something like that - I was starting at 0 (totally forget they start at 1). Will retry. thanks for the response I appreciate it.

Comment: What you've done was fine (the edit was unnecessary), you only forgot one step.

`math.random()` returns a decimal value, you must either to use `math.floor` or `math.ceil` you may also add this function to round to the closet value `math.round = function(d)mf,mc=math.floor(d),math.ceil(d); return (mf + 0.5 > d and mf or mc) end;`

Comment: So basically your function should have been this (only change I've made was adding math.round)
`math.round = function(d)mf,mc=math.floor(d),math.ceil(d); return (mf + 0.5 > d and mf or mc) end;
function getRandomNumber()
 return cards[math.round((math.random() * 1000) * % 4)]
end`